# Liquid glucose stuck furniture

Tags: glucose-syrup

Since I was trying to make some marshmallows for the first time, I bought liquid glucose as was mentioned in the recipe. But, because of mishandling, the cap off the plastic container was not closed properly by me, and I kept it in a storage cupboard as it was. Now somehow it fell inside the cupboard and spilled inside it. It has now jammed the cupboard door. The problem is that it continues to spill and will soon waste the whole lot.

How can I dissolve this liquid glucose in order to open the door?

Comment: I wonder if a hair dryer is good enough to soften it enough to actually open it...

Comment: What material is your cupboard made out of?

Comment: Cupboard is made of some kind of wood

Comment: @JourneymanGeek just don't caramelize it in place :)

Comment: So what should I do to dissolve this glucose and open the door to save the rest of it??? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glucose is water soluble, so you can use water to make it return to liquid phase. You can also probably use some penetrating oil / water displacing spray like WD40, which can also help a lot if some of it ended up on the cabinet door hinges.

Comment: but its wood, water will destroy it, won't it??

Comment: Water is your best chance. Most wood used in kitchens is treated in stone way to perfect it from water, so you can clean it. If yours isn't, it's ruined anyway because the glucose syrup is water-based and would have soaked in. I suggest hot water and plenty of it, but try to free it up as quickly as possible (which might not be very quick)

Comment: water does not necessarily destroy wood, otherwise humanity would not have used it to build ships, piers, homes, and all sorts of stuff that are regularly exposed to water